# Xcode Extension parent no updating on scheme changes

Tags: ios, xcode

Was wondering if someone could help me out. I have a an Xcode project set up with 1 main app target with 2 schemes (dev, live). Each scheme has a different bundle ID so that i can have both apps installed on the device at the same time. All is working fine, although I’m now trying to also add an notification extension. I have set the bundle id of the extension to be dynamic so that it matches its parent id. Although, when building from dev scheme it stills says the parent id does not match. Live seems to be build fine. Im not sure what I’m doing wrong. It looks like the extension doesn’t get built when i change schemes. Any suggestions have i can have 1 extension and 2 different schemes? Thanks  :)

[image: Extensions PLIST]

Basically i need to have both schemes with different bundle IDs because i want both versions of the application installed on the device at one time. I also have dev APNS set up which wouldn't be doable if i used the same bundle id for both schemes

Also found an open radar for this also
https://www.openradar.appspot.com/17301691

Comment: Please include a screenshot of your project settings to see how you are setting up the bundle ID.

Comment: Added the 2 screenshots above